# Certificate verify failed python urlopen windows computer

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, urllib

Just downloaded anaconda (python 3.6) to a windows computer- now I am having trouble running some old code to scrape a website.

```
    import urllib.request
    import urllib3
    urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    print(f.read(300))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'lxml')
```

When I run this with url = 'http://fivethirtyeight.com/' everything works. When I run it with url = 'https://www.wunderground.com' or 'https://weather.com' I get this error:

```
    "URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)>"
```

On other stackoverflow questions for this issue on OSX systems they say to run "/Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command". I am on a windows computer though, and it works for some websites, so I am not sure if this applies- if it does please give me explicit instructions on where/how to run that command - thanks!